# how to generate a zero-mean Gaussian random vector ,which have correlation matrices whose eigenvalues are exponentially distributed

Tags: math, signal-processing, computer-science, eigenvector

1.This is a question from paper "Fast Generalized Eigenvector Tracking Based on the Power Method".

2.The author wrote "We generate two zero-mean  Gaussian random vectors ,which have correlation  matrices A and B whose eigenvalues are **exponentially distributed**".

3.But how to generate a zero-mean  Gaussian random vector ,which have correlation  matrices whose eigenvalues are exponentially distributed ,this confused me almost a week.

4.It seems that we could only use **randn** in MATLAB to generate random vector,
so the problem is how to make sure correlation matrices whose eigenvalues exponentially distributed **at the same time**?

Comment: @JackMoody um, the linked-to question doesn't appear to be relevant, since OP is not sampling from a discrete distribution.

Comment: @RobertDodier you're right. If he really needed it/was already using Numpy, [`numpy.random.poisson`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.poisson.html) could be used.

Comment: if you are using c++ there is a family of libraries called boost which offers api calls to give you similar ... its worth researching boost to gain appreciation of what is demanded and offered by such a powerful set of api's  - its the workhorse of c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let S be a positive definite matrix. Therefore S has a Cholesky decomposition L.L' = S where L is a lower-triangular matrix and `'` denotes the matrix transpose and `.` denotes matrix multiplication. Let x be drawn from a Gaussian distribution with mean zero and covariance equal to the identity matrix. Then y = L.x has a Gaussian distribution with mean zero and covariance S.

So if you can find suitable covariance matrices A and B, you can use their Cholesky decompositions to generate samples. Now about constructing a matrix which has eigenvalues following a given distribution. My advice is to start with a list of samples from an exponential distribution; these will be your eigenvalues. Let E = a matrix with the exponential samples on the diagonal and zeros otherwise. Let U be any unitary matrix (i.e. columns are orthogonal and norm of each column is 1). Then U.E.U' is a positive definite matrix with the specified eigenvalues.

U can be any unitary matrix. In particular U can be the identity matrix. That might make everything else simpler; you'll have to verify whether U = identity is workable for the problem you're working on.

Comment: "Let x be drawn from a Gaussian distribution with mean zero and covariance equal to the identity matrix". I just wondering how to make sure convariance is identity, that is , x.x'= I , I think I got your idea with only this last detail I'm not clear if in MATLAB.

Comment: You describe how to generate samples with the covariance matrix having the required eigenvalue distribution. But the OP asked about the correlation matrix. WIll it have the required eigenvalue distriburion?

Comment: Well, in the paper, It assumes that eigenpair A and B is unknown, so we update A ,B like A(k) = A(k-1) + x(k).x(k)' and B(k) =B(k-1) +n(k).n(k)'. My question is how to generate the vector as the paper told "We generate two zero-mean Gaussian random vectors ,which have correlation matrices A and B whose eigenvalues are exponentially distributed".

Comment: My target is generating  the vector so that it satisfies the conditions from the paper

Comment: Because this paper focus on tracking algorithm, firstly we have A and B for ground truth. But actually they are unknown so we update it by our observation,(initialization for A and B are identity)and update by this observed gaussian random vector. the gaussian random vector contains the information "the vector have correlation matrices A and B whose eigenvalues are exponentially distributed". And in each iteration what we face is how to generate the gaussian random vector so that update our matrices.

Comment: @dmuir You're right, I didn't mention that point. I assume that one can construct a covariance matrix from a correlation matrix.

Comment: @Harry_Cai If x(1), x(2), x(3), ..., x(n) are independent samples from a Gaussian distribution with mean 0 and variance 1, then the vector x = (x(1), ..., x(n)) is a sample from an n-dimensional Gaussian with mean (0, ..., 0) and covariance matrix equal to the identity matrix.

Comment: @Harry_Cai I don't know exactly what's going on, but it sounds like the authors are assuming you start with an initial guess for A and a guess for B and then you update your guesses with incoming data.

Comment: @RobertDodier If C is the covariance matrix and s the diagonal matrix with the square roots of the diagonal elements of C (ie the sd's) then the correlation matrix is (1/s)*C*(1/s). But will the spectrum of that be exponentially distributed if that of C is ?

Comment: @RobertDodier Exactly, it seems that they have ground truth for A,B then update my guess with observed random gaussian vector(the vector contains information from ground truth, i.e. correlation of the vector is somehow A,B). From my experiments result, the way(cholesky decompose then y=L.x) I used to generate vector to update matrices converge much faster than the result from paper.